# How to surround with quotes the second word of every line (Vim)?

Tags: regex, vim

In other words, how do I get form this:

```
isDefault 初期設定
none 無
buyNow すぐ購入
```

To this?

```
isDefault '初期設定'
none '無'
buyNow 'すぐ購入'
```

EDIT:

I only know how to do that to the first line:

```
:%s/\<\w\+\>/'&'/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` can't match Japanese characters. So, I would use `\s.*$` to match word after space in each line. Here is the command

```
:%s/\(\s\+\)\(.*\)$/\1'\2'
```

Comment: vimgolf: `:%norm wC'<c-v><c-r>"'`

Comment: Very glad to see a real vim way solution while this is my first vim answer. It's more valuable than any reputation I earned. @PeterRincker, could you explain further about <c-v><c-r>"? I understand <c-r>, <c-r> individually, but can't understand why visual mode blockwise and redo are used here.

Comment: Practical VIM saved me. <c-v> is [Insert Unusual Characters by Character Code](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/practical-vim-2nd/9781680501629/f_0038.html) and <c-r>" is [Paste from a Register Without Leaving Insert Mode](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/practical-vim-2nd/9781680501629/f_0036.html). However, could you help explain how trigger these in Insert Mode? After I typed <c-v><c-r>, upper case R is inserted.

Comment: Do you have `<c-v>` remapped in insert mode? What does `:imap <c-v>` give you? You can also use `<c-q>` instead of `<c-v>` (`<c-q>` is also used for flow control so your milage may vary).

Comment: `:imap <c-v>` says 'no mapping found'. I'm using latest version of MacVim.

Comment: Try using `<c-q>` instead. I have tested this on MacVim and it works, however it is not quite the latest and greatest. Try running Vim without your vimrc, `mvim -u NONE -N`. If you it still is not working then you may want to submit a bug report

Comment: Finally, I made it work in vim under terminal with `<c-q>`. Its version is 8.0, patch 1-72 . It never works in MacVim even with `mvim -u NONE -N`. Its version is 8.0 patch 1-525. Thanks for the help, @PeterRincker. Your answer forced me to learn more about `:h i_CTRL-*`, which I rarely used before.